# Trying to setup webserver and not able to access from outside network

Tags: apache2

So here's the deal. I'm new to apache and just installed it today. I got the dirs setup and when I type my IP address (from my ISP) into a browser it pulls up the site fine, but when I try to access it from outside my home network using the same IP I get a 404 not found. I've got port forwarding setup on my router for port 80 and my I checked with my ISP to make sure they didn't block port 80 incoming connections. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Alright, So I tried a different port even though my ISP said they didn't block em... they lied. Solution found, but I'll give the correct answer to TheX for responding so fast ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the IP address in DMZ (Demilitarized Zone).

For me it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may not be your ISP. if you're on cable/dsl log into your modem's properties. Most of them now-adays come pre-equipped with a firewall as well. I had to disable the firewall on my Motorola Surfboard cable modem to serve up my own Port 80 content.